# Spring Hibernate ConverterNotFoundException ManyToMany

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring v3.2.6, Hibernate v4.2.2.

Here is my SecurityUser object:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class SecurityUser implements UserDetails {

    //@Transient
    //private final String PERMISSION_PREFIX = "ROLE_PERMISSION_";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="USR_ID")
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    @Column(name="USR_USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    @Column(name="USR_PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="USER_ROLE_MAPPINGS",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USR_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="RLE_ID")})
    private Set<SecurityRole> roles = new HashSet<SecurityRole>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Set<GrantedAuthorityImpl> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthorityImpl>();
        for (SecurityRole role : this.roles) {
            for (SecurityPermission permission : role.getPermissions()) {
                GrantedAuthorityImpl gAuthorities = 
                        new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_PERMISSION_" + permission.getPermission());
                authorities.add(gAuthorities);
            }
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

//  public String toString() {
//        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
//    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<SecurityRole> getRoles() {
        return this.roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<SecurityRole> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

And here is my SecurityRole object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class SecurityRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="RLE_ID")
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    @Column(name="RLE_ROLE")
    private String role;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="ROLE_PERMISSION_MAPPINGS",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="RLE_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PRM_ID")})
    private Set<SecurityPermission> permissions = new HashSet<SecurityPermission>();

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Set<SecurityPermission> getPermissions() {
        return this.permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(Set<SecurityPermission> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

//  public String toString() {
//        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
//    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When I run my application to display a list of users, I am getting the following error message:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet eGarage threw exception
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type @javax.persistence.ManyToMany @javax.persistence.JoinTable org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet<@javax.persistence.ManyToMany @javax.persistence.JoinTable com.motodoc.egarage.domain.SecurityRole> to type java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:276)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:172)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.ExpressionUtils.convertTypedValue(ExpressionUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.EvalTag.doEndTag(EvalTag.java:126)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx._jspx_meth_spring_005feval_005f5(table_tagx.java:2180)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f25(table_tagx.java:2147)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f1(table_tagx.java:2114)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f1(table_tagx.java:1905)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fforTokens_005f1(table_tagx.java:1805)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f3(table_tagx.java:1739)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(table_tagx.java:339)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.fields.table_tagx.doTag(table_tagx.java:260)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.securityusers.list_jspx._jspx_meth_table_005ftable_005f0(list_jspx.java:116)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.securityusers.list_jspx.access$0(list_jspx.java:98)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.securityusers.list_jspx$Helper.invoke0(list_jspx.java:195)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.securityusers.list_jspx$Helper.invoke(list_jspx.java:223)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(list_tagx.java:435)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(list_tagx.java:403)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx.access$0(list_tagx.java:393)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx$Helper.invoke0(list_tagx.java:517)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx$Helper.invoke(list_tagx.java:534)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.panel_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(panel_tagx.java:184)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.util.panel_tagx.doTag(panel_tagx.java:130)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx._jspx_meth_util_005fpanel_005f0(list_tagx.java:388)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(list_tagx.java:212)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.form.list_tagx.doTag(list_tagx.java:176)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.securityusers.list_jspx._jspx_meth_page_005flist_005f0(list_jspx.java:93)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.securityusers.list_jspx._jspService(list_jspx.java:63)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:968)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:650)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(default_jspx.java:224)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspService(default_jspx.java:87)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my webmvc-config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller annotation. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.motodoc.egarage.controller" use-default-filters="true">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources -->
    <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <!-- Allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" by forwarding static resource 
    requests to the container's default Servlet -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- Register "global" interceptor beans to apply to all registered HandlerMappings -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="lang"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Selects a static view for rendering without the need for an explicit controller -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/login"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/uncaughtException"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/resourceNotFound"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/dataAccessFailure"/>

    <!-- Resolves localized messages*.properties and application.properties files in the application to allow for internationalization. 
    The messages*.properties files translate Roo generated messages which are part of the admin interface, the 
    application.properties resource bundle localizes all application specific messages such as entity names and menu items. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>

    <!-- Store preferred language configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver" id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale"/>

    <!-- Resolves localized <theme_name>.properties files in the classpath to allow for theme support -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource" id="themeSource"/>

    <!-- Store preferred theme configuration in a cookie -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard"/>

    <!-- This bean resolves specific types of exceptions to corresponding logical - view names for error views. 
    The default behaviour of DispatcherServlet - is to propagate all exceptions to the servlet 
    container: this will happen - here with all other types of exceptions. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key=".DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
                <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">resourceNotFound</prop>
                <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">resourceNotFound</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable this for integration of file upload functionality -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" id="multipartResolver"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
  </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
      <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
        <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The error occurs when I click on a URL which invokes the following method in the Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String list(
        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, 
        @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, 
        @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, 
        @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, 
        Model uiModel) {

    if (page != null || size != null) {
        int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
        final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("securityusers", securityUserService.findSecurityUserEntries(firstResult, sizeNo));
        float nrOfPages = (float) securityUserService.countAllSecurityUsers() / sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
    } 
    else {
        uiModel.addAttribute("securityusers", securityUserService.findAllSecurityUsers());
    }
    return "securityusers/list";
}
```

Can someone please help resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm using Maven so I've added webmvc-confile file and extracts from POM file as well.

Comment: What are you doing when generating the exception? It has nothing to do with Hibernate really. Your request fails because there is no conversion possible from `PersistenSet<SecurityRole>` to `String`.

Comment: Can you please explain further? How/where do I add the necessary conversion?

Comment: @Bart I have updated original question which explains when the error occurs.

Comment: I think the problem is in the view, how are you rendering the `securityusers` attribute added to your `uiModel`?

Comment: You should render a property of the `SecurityRole` instance and not the whole object. For instance `${securityRole.role}`.

Comment: i'm having a similiar problem here (String to OneToMany) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608519/string-to-type-onetomany-converter-spring-hibernate